# Invoke a bytecode class method, java

Tags: java, class, assembly, java-bytecode-asm

Im new to java, (i use to program in .NET, Lua ...) and i started to use ASM.
so i can't use any methods of the class "Foo", how can i invoke these methods?

many thanks...

code:

```
package com.teste;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.FieldVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;

public class nclass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class<?> klass = new ClassLoader(nclass.class.getClassLoader()) {
        public Class<?> defineClass() {

            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
            FieldVisitor fv;
            MethodVisitor mv;
            //
            Label l0;
            Label l1;

            cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_6, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_SUPER,
                    "Foo", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                fv = cw.visitField(0, "value" + i, "I", null, null);
                fv.visitAnnotation("LBar;", true).visitEnd();
            }

            fv = cw.visitField(Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "nome", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, null);
            fv.visitEnd();

            mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(2, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
            l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "Lsimple;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();

            mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "setNome", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(6, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, "simple", "nome", "Ljava/lang/String;");
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
            l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("value", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();

            mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "getNome", "()Ljava/lang/String;", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(7, l0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "simple", "nome", "Ljava/lang/String;");
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ARETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 0);
            mv.visitEnd();


            cw.visitEnd();

            byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();

            return defineClass("Foo", bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }.defineClass();

    for (Field f : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println(f + " " + Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));
    }

    for (Field f : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println(f + " " + f.getName());
    }

    for (Method f : klass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        System.out.println(f + " " + Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));
    }

    Class<?> c= klass.forName("Foo");

    Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("getNome", String.class);
    System.out.println(method.invoke(c));

   }

}
```

*** NEW CODE WORKING ***

```
package com;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.FieldVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;

public class simple {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
 * @throws SecurityException 
 * @throws InvocationTargetException 
 * @throws IllegalAccessException 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,      NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

    Class<?> klass = new ClassLoader(simple.class.getClassLoader()) {
        public Class<?> defineClass() {

            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
            FieldVisitor fv;
            MethodVisitor mv;
            //
            Label l0;
            Label l1;

            cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_6, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_SUPER,
                    "simple", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                fv = cw.visitField(0, "value" + i, "I", null, null);
                fv.visitAnnotation("LBar;", true).visitEnd();
            }

            fv = cw.visitField(Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "nome", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, null);
            fv.visitEnd();

            mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(2, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
            l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "Lsimple;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();

            mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "setNome", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(6, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, "simple", "nome", "Ljava/lang/String;");
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
            l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("value", "Ljava/lang/String;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();

            mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "getNome", "()Ljava/lang/String;", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(7, l0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "simple", "nome", "Ljava/lang/String;");
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ARETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 0);
            mv.visitEnd();


            cw.visitEnd();

            byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();

            return defineClass("simple", bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }.defineClass();

    for (Field f : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println(f + " " + Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));
    }

    for (Field f : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println(f + " " + f.getName());
    }

    for (Method f : klass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        System.out.println(f + " " + Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));
    }
    Method  setNome = klass.getDeclaredMethod("setNome", String.class);
    Method  getNome = klass.getDeclaredMethod("getNome");

    setNome.invoke(klass,"this sucks!");

    System.out.println(getNome.invoke(null));

}

}
```

Thanks Paŭlo Ebermann, next step i ll try class loading with instance ( i think something like "Class s= new simple()" ).

Comment: What is the actual result of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is here:

```
 Class<?> c= klass.forName("Foo");

 Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("getNome", String.class);
 System.out.println(method.invoke(c));
```

`klass.forName("Foo")` is actually equivalent to `Class.forName("Foo")`, which results in `Class.forName("Foo", nclass.class.getClassLoader());`.

The class loader which loaded `nclass` obviously does not know a `Foo` class, since it was created by your anonymous class loader (which is a child of this class loader). So, don't use this `forName` call here, but simply use your `klass` object to get the method and invoke it.

---

And of course, invoking and retrieving a method works not like you did.

- The `getMethod` and `getDeclaredMethod` take beside the name a list of argument types (not return types) - in your case `getNome` has no arguments, so it should be:

  ```
  Method  method = klass.getDeclaredMethod ("getNome");
  ```
- the invoke methods first argument is an object of the methods receiving type (`Foo` in your case), or `null` for static methods. The following arguments are the parameters to the method (i.e. none in your case). So you should use here:

  ```
  System.out.println(method.invoke(null));
  ```

  It may be that the argument is simply ignored in your case, so `c` might not get an error. But there still is no reason to use a class object here, if you are not actually invoking a method of class `Class` by reflection.

This all is assuming your error occurs in your `forName` call and not already earlier. Please learn to describe your error message, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: i found a bug, i messed some declarations "simple" and "Foo" and then resulting in a error, thanks for your quick explanation! ...